# yum installation error

Tags: software-installation, yum, libreoffice

I know I have `file:///root/repo` as the **baseurl** of my **/etc/yum.repos.d/batch.repo** file. 
I want to install libreoffice, but I get the below message when i run the cmd `[root@localhost ~]# yum install libreoffice`.

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-
              : manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
file:///root/repo/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /root/repo/repodata/repomd.xml"
Trying other mirror.
No package libreoffice available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@localhost ~]#
```

What am I not understanding or doing wrong (I'm new to Linux and using RHEL7)?

Answer (score 2):

The output from your `yum` command includes this line

> This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use `subscription-manager` to register.

You're not licensed to use the RedHat subscription service. You need to buy a licence, or if you already have one you need to install it.

Comment: Your observation is well noted, but that is not the cause of the error, it is only a notification that i have no subscription for RHEL. Consulted with my tutors and the error has to do with my repo settings. The device from which my baseurl is built from (is) not (properly) entered in my fstab file and i dont have the libre package in it.